# How to make this linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq

I got a Database where I have data with an attribute like '12.34.56.78'.

To get this data I use

```
using (Data context = new Data(connection, compiledModel, true))
{
}
```

Now I want to only get the data where the first and second number is the same as my values.

I already tried this:

```
myData = context.Where(x => x.Numbers.Split('.')[0] == firstNumber && x.Numbers.Split('.')[1] == secondNumber)
```

But this only get me this error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.'

How do I write this expression to get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `IQueryable` queries, you should always think about how it will be translated into an SQL query.

How would you do this with simple SQL query?
There is no `Split` in SQL, so you will probably do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Numbers LIKE '12.34.%'
```

This is an equivalent to the following LINQ:

```
string prefix = $"{firstNumber}.{secondNumber}.";
myData = context.Where(x => x.Numbers.StartsWith(prefix));
```